# What is the alternative to WebIntent on iOS in Ionic 4?

Tags: ios, ionic4, inappbrowser

I need to open an App and get the response it returns after a choice. I'm doing it with the WebIntent plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent) for android and it works. Now i'm trying to do the same thing for iOS, i'm using InAppBrowser (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) but there is a bug, if you open an app with a link using target: "_system" the event listeners are not triggered. Are there other ways to do this in iOS?

Example of WebIntent:

```
      const options = {
        action: this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
        url: 'app://url',
        extras: {
          my_extras: 'extras'
        }
      };

      this.webIntent.startActivityForResult(options).then((intent) => {
        if (intent.extras.resultCode === -1) {
          this.doSomething(intent.extras);
        } else {
          // handle errors
        }
      }, (error) => {
        // handle case when app is not installed
      });
```

Example of my try with InAppBrowser

```
      let browser = this.iab.create('app://url', '_system');

      browser.on('exit').subscribe((event) => {
        console.log('exit'); // this event is fired actually
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });

      browser.on('message').subscribe(event => {
        console.log('message'); // all other events like this one are not fired
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Thanks for any help!

-- EDIT --
So i've found a way online to use listeners in InAppBrowser with _system target. You have to create the browser with _blank target then reopen it in the event handler with _system target.
Example:

```
openBrowser() {
  const url = 'app://url'
  const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank');
  browser.on('beforeload').subscribe(evt => {
    this.beforeloadEventHandler(evt, url);
  }
  // close the blank browser where you want
  browser.close();
}
public beforeloadEventHandler(event, url) {
  const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_system');
  browser.on('beforeload').subscribe(evt => {
    this.beforeloadEventHandler(evt, url);
  });

  // your logic
  console.log('beforeload evt');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

But in the end this solution does not work for me cause i don't get any data back with InAppBrowser listeners, i guess there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative is to use capacitor API

```
App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
    // data.url contains the url that is opening your app
    // so you can use it to check what to do
});

const canOpen = await App.canOpenUrl({ url: 'app://url' });
if (canOpen.value === true) {
    // can open 'app://url'
}
const open = await App.openUrl({ url: 'app://url' });
if (!open.completed) {
    // app not opened, custom logic like ask to install the app or redirect to the store
}
```